# How can I move a file on a FTP server without download/upload?

Tags: ftp

I'm having to use FTP on a client project, which is proving pretty painful as I usually use my own servers and ssh, etc.

One apparent limit of FTP that doesn't seem to make sense crops up when I'm trying to shift files between two directories that are both on the server. It seems that with FTP all of the files have to be downloaded to the local machine (i.e., the machine running the FTP client) first, and then re-uploaded to the remote server.

Is there any way round this if I'm only using FTP?

Comment: What FTP server is in use?  Some FTP servers support the help command which will tell you what functions it supports.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/B8tWz6ew lists the functions supported on the server

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the FTP server, but try "rename [filename] [newfilename]".

rename [filename] [/dir/newdir/filename]